# How to change interface language in MS Office for Mac 2011

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-office, language

I have MS Office for Mac downloaded from http://de.msoffice13.com/mac (I found this link and product key in instructions) . Everything works ok but interface language is German. I have "Preferred language" - English in Settings and all <del>normal</del> other applications installs with English interface but not MSOffice.
[image] Please suggest me how can I change MSOffice's language.

UPDATE:

I have downloaded DMG from http://us.msoffice13.com/mac and tried to install it but nothing changed. Maybe I should try to completely delete previous version first (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2398768)? Also both DMGs (from http://us.msoffice13.com/mac and http://de.msoffice13.com/mac) have the same size so I think they both may include all languages inside.

Comment: Hoping to contribute,
I have installed Office for Mac 2011 from retail, Italian version,
and I have OS "Language and Preferences" set to "English" and "Region = United States" (where original poster had set "Englsh" and "Region = Germany").
Same problem, I'm trying to change user interface language from Italian to English. (so, likely we can exclude the problem lies in the "Region = ..." setting, or in the fact that the original poster's install was from a downloaded file).